# AudioContext Live Streaming

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

What is the correct way to play live stream with use of WebAudio API.

I am trying with following code, however all I see is that MP3 is being downloaded, but not played; probably MediaElementSource expect a file, not continuous stream.

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();

var audio = new Audio();
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(context.destination);
audio.src = '<live mp3 stream>';
audio.play();
```

Comment: If you want people to help you, it will be handy to add the url of the mp3 livestream, as I think an audio element should be able to play that (although don't pin me on that). If we have the url, we can try some debugging.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  audio.play();
}, false);
```

Comment: Is it possible that MP3 is not supported for streaming? I have tried with ogg and it worked. Using mp3 stream it doesn't work, although that VLC plays it.

Comment: @JurePolutnik did you answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe miss `audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous"` for hosted live stream with CORS enabled.

This is my whole working solution, MP3 as well:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const context = new AudioContext();

const audio = new Audio();
audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // Useful to play hosted live stream with CORS enabled

const sourceAudio = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
sourceAudio.connect(context.destination);

const playHandler = () => {
  audio.play();
  audio.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', playHandler);
};
const errorHandler = e => {
  console.error('Error', e);
  audio.removeEventListener('error', errorHandler);
};

audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', playHandler, false);
audio.addEventListener('error', errorHandler);

audio.src = '<live mp3 stream>';
```